# JQuery POST Data to Rails DB

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, post

Following the tutorial [here](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=566149), I have created a Rails project, and uploaded it to Heroku. It is a DB that takes in scores for a highscore db, and lists them in a json file. I am able to upload a score using Curl, with this command:

```
 curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"score":1337,"id":null,"name":"SuperDude"}'  http://warm-hamlet-9230.herokuapp.com/highscores
```

However when I try to use a .ajax request, I don't see anything happening, as you can see in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9dxT/1/). Why does this code not work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: url gives error 404 not found

Comment: http://warm-hamlet-9230.herokuapp.com/highscores   check it using firebug

Comment: @Dave OK, why would the URL work with curl, but give a 404 with firebug?

Comment: this could be the cross domain policy issue